# Shell Script Behaves Different Depending on the PC I SSH From

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a shell script.

```
curl -s https://steamcharts.com/app/570940 | iconv -f windows-1251 | grep -Po -m 1 "(?<=>)[0-9]{1,4}(?=<\/span)"
```

*Any improvements you would make to this? (I'm fairly new to Unix)

The script is located on a RPI which I SSH to from either:

1. Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu)
2. Termux

If I run it from an SSH session started from my PC it works successfully and returns a number.

However when running it from my phone I get the following error:

```
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 81
```

Why is this happening?
Why does the computer I am SSHing from make a difference?

EDIT:

```
< LANG=C.UTF-8
> LANG=en_US.UTF-8
< TERM=screen
> TERM=xterm-256color
```

The above is the result of running:

```
diff lt.txt tm.txt | grep -P "(TERM|LANG)"
```

The only other differences are to do with the SSH session.

Comment: Write another shell script `printenv | sort` and compare the output when calling it from different client devices. There might be differences in the TERM or locale settings. For details, you'll have to investigate the login and profile scripts that are executed when you ssh to the machine.

Comment: @RolandWeber Is there any sensitive data in my environment variables? I can see my external IP is different SSH_CLIENT, SSH_CONNECTION, SSH_TTY, TERM and LANG.

Comment: LANG is one of the locale settings and might affect the behavior of `iconv`.

Comment: @RolandWeber I have edited the question to include the differences between my "printenv" output. You suggested investigating my login and profile scripts? I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: Look for files `~/.login`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, or a bunch of others that depend on the shell you're using. The documentation of your shell will tell you what files are executed in what order at the time of login.

Comment: @RolandWeber Is this on the SSHer or SSHee? My Raspberry Pi or Termux or PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `iconv` command specifies the input encoding with `-f`, but not the output encoding with `-t`. So `iconv` has to guess the output encoding, based on the setting of LANG.

Add the `-t` option with your desired output encoding and the problem should be gone (I hope).

While LANG specifies UTF-8 in both cases, it's possible that one of the two locales is not installed, and therefore leads to a wrong guess by `iconv`.

Comment: Thanks! Using "-t UTF-8" has sorted my problem :)